# Altering vertical space between lines of one breqn (dmath) equation

Tags: spacing, breqn

The [breqn documentation](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/mh/breqn.pdf) says that

> It also makes it possible to specify different vertical space values
>   for the space between lines of a long, broken equation and the space
>   between separate equations in a group of equations.

This suggests you can adjust the vertical space between the lines of one `dmath` environment, but what is that command? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: There are many possible answers to your question.  It would help if you provided an example, starting with `\documentclass` to help us see the particulars.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Another thing: I wouldn't use [`breqn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) at all; Michael Downes never finished the package before he passed away and Morten Høgholm didn't finished it after MIchael before he (Morten) retracting from the LaTeX community so there are a lot of unfinished stuff in the package (as far as I understand it).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Did anything change in this matter?
I'm quite content with what dmath does, only the interline spacing is too large, and there seems to be no way to change it. Those parameters in the 1st answer do not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

`breqn.sty` has the following comments that presumably relate to the lengths you want

```
\eqlinespacing=14pt plus2pt % Base-to-base space between lines

\eqlineskip=3pt plus2pt % Min space if eqlinespacing too small

\intereqskip=3pt plus2pt % Additional vert space between equations
```